# add a class to PHP

Tags: php, html, class, hyperlink

When a user uploads a sound it displays it in a database table as a link. The link should have class="sm2_button" within it, When this is done within a PHP file it is giving a syntax error

```
echo "<td><a href='http://website.com/sound/".$sound['downloadlink']."' class="sm2_button">Play/</a></td>";
```

Comment: please familiarize your self with :https://php.net/language.types.string

Comment: so it just needs single quotes in php? the error is gone.

Comment: well if the error is gone then clearly .. yes - there is about 5 way to build this string. but what ever works is fine

Comment: What I was trying to do works, Thank you Dagon! , lol I now see it was a very simple thing

Comment: simple, you need to escape the quotes here `class="sm2_button"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: use single quotes to add class in php
Example: class=''

```
echo "<td><a href='http://website.com/sound/".$sound['downloadlink']."' class='sm2_button'>Play/</a></td>";
```

Comment: `class=\"sm2_button\"` would have been just as good, if not better. that's what I mean by "escaping" the quotes.

Comment: or `echo "<td><a href='http://website.com/sound/{$sound['downloadlink']}' class='sm2_button'>Play/</a></td>";` or several others :-)

Comment: Thanks Fred and Dagon! it seems there are almost infinite possibilities to achieve the same outcome when coding.